# Do I need to keep a file open after calling mmap on it?

Tags: c, mmap

I have a program that maps quite a few (100's) of sizable files 10-100MB each. I need them all mapped at the same time.

At the moment I am calling `open` followed by `mmap` at the beginning of the program, followed by `munmap` and `close` at the end.

Often I have to adjust the open files limit running `ulimit -n` before running the program.

Question is do I actually need to keep the files open, or can I `open` `mmap` `close` do some large data processing then `munmap` when I'm finished.

The man pages of `mmap` do not seem terribly clear to me on this one.

Comment: You can see it in a system call trace (e.g. `strace`) of an executable, that the mappings for shared libraries follow the pattern: open the descriptor, mmap it, close the descriptor.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

No, at least not on Linux it's fine to close the file.

[The manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) clearly states:

> On the other hand, closing the file descriptor does not unmap the region.

For portability, I also checked the [POSIX manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/mmap.html), it says the same thing (although even more clearly):

> The *mmap()* function adds an extra reference to the file associated with the file descriptor *fildes* which is not removed by a subsequent *close()* on that file descriptor. This reference is removed when there are no more mappings to the file.

Comment: why `proc/<pid>/fd` does not contain information on the mmapped files? Is it because `mmap` is a `syscall`, so these fds are on kernel's data structures? _asking for a friend_