# What is the behaviour of an mmap()'ed pointer after closing the file descriptor without first calling munmap()?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, posix

Consider the following code fragment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int fd = open( "/path/to/existing/file/or/device", O_RDONLY);
int numberOfWords = 4096; // chosen to be smaller than file size
int* data = mmap( NULL, nomberOfWords * sizeof(int), PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0); 
if (data != MAP_FAILED) {

   printf( "%d\n", data[0]);

   // oops, forgot to munmap

   close(fd);

   printf( "%d\n", data[0]);        // <-- why doesn't this segfault

}
```

#### Background

I am working with a custom kernel driver that uses `ioctl()` to setup for DMA, and ultimately requires user space to use `mmap()` to access a particular buffer.

While developing unit tests I discovered accidentally that after closing the file descriptor without calling `munmap` first, it was still possible to access the buffer memory in user space with the mmap'ed pointer. Thinking there was some bug in the driver I wrote a small program similar to that shown here to exercise mmap() with a "normal" file.

What I was expecting to see is a segfault on the read after close, my thinking being, that the kernel would automatically `munmap()` the pages associated with the file descriptor when the use of the open file descriptor was closed, similar to how it happens when the process is terminated.

Instead, I was able to keep using the pointer.  This was a bit surprising as I have been using `mmap()` for several years, I must have been smart (more likely lucky) enough to avoid bugs that would expose this situation.  Nothing was obvious in the `mmap` man page.

#### Problem

Ideally our driver will need to cause a segfault in user space if this happens, because we don't want a buggy user space program writing to the memory of interest.

So, is this behaviour the same across different *nix? In the given example, would it take say deleting the file to cause a segfault? Or perhaps flushing the vm caches?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, after writing most of the question I found this different question which is worded differently from how I was searching: [do I need to keep a file open after calling mmap on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490033/do-i-need-to-keep-a-file-open-after-calling-mmap-on-it)

The answer references the POSIX manual and it turns out in the man page after all (under `munmap`, in passing :-| ) it is explained that closing the descriptor will not automatically unmap the mapping.  So it looks like we need to modify our driver close code to invalidate associated memory mappings so that a segfault will occur in user space.

I decided to post the question in case someone else searches for a similar thing.

Comment: It is _wrong_ for your driver to invalidate a memory mapping just because the file has been closed.  The documented behavior of `mmap` is that you can _keep using_ a mmap-ed region after the file has been closed.  Your driver should get a notification from the core kernel when mappings actually go away, as well as when each file descriptor is closed.

Answer (score 1):

The [man page for mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) states the following:

> After the mmap() call has returned, the file descriptor, fd, can be closed immediately without invalidating the mapping.

This was added explicitly [in August 2018](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git/commit/man2/mmap.2?id=3ee0a7f07ed1bd607e598bc4477af0dea5db4084), meaning in the man pages for the 5.x Linux kernels.