# reading a memory mapped file after it's closed

Tags: ios, linux, unix, operating-system, mmap

The `mmap` man pages indicate that closing a file does not result in unmapping of pages. However, I wonder if the following sequence is valid that by the time the read occurs the pages have likely not have been faulted into memory. In other words, is the file still open after the `close` ? Also is the behavior expected on both Android and iOS?

```
void func()
{
   auto fd    = open("test.txt", O_RDONLY);
   void *ptr  = mmap(nullptr, 16384, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
   close(fd);
   uint8_t *p = (uint8_t *)ptr;
   // Read from *p 
}
```

Comment: You should try it and post an update on if it worked. In theory this shouldn't work at all.

Comment: it works and hence my question, if it's always expected to work

Comment: Interesting. Curious to know the answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need to keep a file open after calling mmap on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490033/do-i-need-to-keep-a-file-open-after-calling-mmap-on-it)

Comment: Seems like mmap adds its own reference to the file so the `fd` is closed, but mmap's internal reference is still open which is why it works.

Comment: mmap adds a reference.  If you close and unlink the file, the disk space will not be freed until you unmap.